# The notion of shadowing property is independent of choice of metric or not?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Can anyone tell me that the notion of shadowing property is independent of choice of metric or not?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. I think a bit more details about what is a shadowing property, and what do you mean by independent, would help other people to answer you.

Comment: The shadowing property depends very much on the metric (not only on the topology). E.g. $f(x) = 2x$ does not have the shadowing property in euclidean $\mathbb{R}^d$, while it has it if $\mathbb{R}^d$ is endowed with a metric inherited from $S^d$ by identifying the latter with the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @mathlove, you have used two profiles on this site - one of them registered, the other one not. Please ask the SE team to join them by accessing https://mathoverflow.net/contact and choosing "I need to merge user profiles" in the subject.